# ¿Se Puede Obtener Una Lista De Archivos De la Carpeta AppFolder GoogleDrive?

Tags: android

he estado probando en mi app varias api y su por estos día he esta probando la api de Google Drive, la pregunta es la siguiente se puede Listar Los Archivos De La Carpeta AppFolder, porque la estado probando y para enviar archivos perfecto pero para listar me da error. Gracias.
MI CODIGO:

```
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.enableAutoManage(this, this)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
.build();



DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(apiClient);

folder.listChildren(apiClient).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
            if (metadataBufferResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                for(Metadata m: metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer())
                    //Aqui obtengo los ficheros
                    Log.i("fichero", "Fichero: " + m.getTitle() + " [" + m.getDriveId().encodeToString() + "]");

            }
            else {
                Log.e("LOGTAG", "Error al listar carpeta");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Este es código base que esta en la documentación de la Api Rest:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata

Para acceder a ciertas carpetas ahi que se OWNER(Dueño) de la carpeta o del grupo.

```
FileList files = driveService.files().list()
        .setSpaces("appDataFolder")
        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
        .setPageSize(10)
        .execute();
for(File file: files.getFiles()) {
    System.out.printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n",
            file.getName(), file.getId());
}
```

Comment: Amigo ese código no le sirve a la api de google drive para android porque no me aparece el File List

Comment: Te sugerimos revisar [answer]